# Loding file on recovery mod

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode, rom, twrp, oneplus-one

I really need to know how to load .zip files on the recovery TWRP. Because I did a system wipe without previously do a flash of the new ROM. There's a way to put the ROM on the phone even without any system on it? Thanks.

Comment: Look into adb sideload.

Answer (score 0):

Loading and flashing a ROM from within TWRP can be done with a few easy steps.

1. Select a ROM and download it to a place on your computer with a simple path such as a folder on your desktop.
2. Open into TWRP and plug your device into your computer.
3. Open the terminal with administrative rights and verify your device is visible with the command `adb devices` if your device is present it will show up.
4. Next throw the command `adb push path_of_the.zip /sdcard/` that should put the ROM.zip in your sdcard.
5. Within TWRP click the install button and navigate to where the ROM.zip file is. In this case it's in the /sdcard and click it then slide the bar